# Context menu: Make Winrar unpack files to specific folder

Tags: context-menu, winrar

I want to add a context menu entry for Winrar (Windows 10) to unpack an archive to a specific folder, like *D:\Test*. Currently I can only choose the default options `Unpack here`, `Unpack...` and `Unpack to $archivename/`. I want to add `Unpack to D:\Test` to that. I cannot find the related keys in the registry.

May be relevant: I did setup Winrar to cascade the context menu, like seen here:
http://www.unlockwindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/WinRAR-Context-Menu-after-tweaking.png (you can do that in Winrars options).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I use 7-zip, it gives better context menu options.

Comment: As far as I can see, I can't that do that from the 7zip GUI either...!?

Comment: I misunderstood the question, you want a specific location in the context menu.